# jqGrid Advanced Search button outside the grid

Tags: jqgrid

I have advanced search button outside the jqGrid. I am using:

```
var pSearch = //How do I get this object as mine is constructed in c# code. How do I get it from jqGrid's property collection or options??

$("#list").jqGrid("searchGrid",pSearch);
```

Comment: @Oleg A question which you find interesting....

Comment: By the way, if you want send a message to me you should post comment with "@Oleg" in the question where I posted an answer or comment. You current comment in new question didn't produced any notification.

Answer (score 0):

The typical usage of `searchGrid` would be

```js
$("#list").jqGrid("searchGrid");
```

or

```js
$("#list").jqGrid("searchGrid", {multipleSearch: true});
```

because all really important options on the Advanced Searching dialog are inside of `colModel`.

I personally prefer the first form and set just common settings by `$.jgrid.search` for the searching in some JavaScript file which I include on every page of the project. For example

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    multipleSearch: true,
    multipleGroup: true,
    recreateFilter: true,
    overlay: 0
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I get the search options multipleSearch,multipleGroup from jqGrid's option's? as I am setting them from c# code.

Comment: @chugh97: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. The `multipleSearch` and `multipleGroup` are the options of searching. There are no such option in jqGrid main module. Moreover I don't understand which relation has C# to the options.

Comment: my options are set up in C# code as we have the source code for jqGrid. There search options are set there. How can I get them in jquery on the client from the jqGrid object?

Comment: @chugh97: Do you really use jqGrid or you use some commercial ASP.NET product like [jqSuite](http://www.trirand.net/download.aspx) and so you wrote about C# code for jqGrid? jqGrid is pure JavaScript library, so you have to set all option in the JavaScript code. Even if you use `<script type="text/javascript">` on the ASPX page you still have to write ordinal *JavaScript* code. So I still not understand what you mean about settings jqGrid options in C# and which "jqGrid objects" you mean.

Comment: we have bought from http://www.trirand.net/download.aspx. This website you can buy the source code so we create the options in C# code and this spits out the jquery code for the grid. Most of heavylifting is done in this dll Trirand.Web.Mvc.dll which actually composes the jquery code in c#.

Comment: @chugh97: Sorry, but you should write this information in your question too. Additionally you should use correct tag of the question. Compare [jqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid/info) with [jqgrid-asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info). I don't use jqSuite myself so I can't help you. Because you bought jqSuite you can get support for the product [here](http://www.trirand.net/support.aspx).